# solr autosuggest with diacritics

Tags: solr, tokenize, diacritics, autosuggest

I'm using solr4 with the `TermsComponent` Autosuggest (as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent))
We're doing a regEx "startsWith"-search, that ignores upper/lower-case, the whole searchQuery looks like this:

```
<solr>/terms
?terms.fl=name
&terms=true
&terms.limit=5
&terms.regex=<term>.*
&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive
&qt=%2Fterms
```

Let me give you a few examples what that returns:

```
test -> Test Listing; test lowercase
Test -> Test Listing; test lowercase
```

Unfortunately, this solution can't handle diacritics, umlaute, accents .. So the following won't work:

```
têst -> Test Listing; test lowercase; Têst áccènt
Test -> Test Listing; test lowercase; Têst áccènt
```

The field is a `string` - I've tried with a tokenized `test_en` as well, but without success

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

What's the best way to enable bidirectional accent-searching for this autosuggest?

---

Edit: Changes for AnalyzerSuggester:

```
  <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="autosuggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="storeDir">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="field">asug</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_asug</str>

      <!-- Suggester properties -->
      <bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/autosuggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>autosuggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

.

```
<fieldType name="text_asug" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the term component works on indexed tokens both for searching and query. So, if you do unicode folding (which is what you do), you will store folded text version. You will match it without accents, but then you will also get it back without accents too.

I can think of two options:

1) Store folded and non-folded term in one field. So somehow get "Têst áccènt" to map to "Test accent|Têst áccènt". You match at the prefix "Test.." and then extract second term on the client. How to do that could be tricky though.

2) Use [Suggester](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) instead. This builds on top of spell-checker and - if I read documentation properly - allows to specify alternative field_type, whose analyzers are used during suggester's index/query (using barely-documented queryAnalyzerFieldType parameter in solrconfig.xml). So, your original text gets copied into suggester in folded form. But, presumable, once Suggester matches something, it will return the original form. However, I am not sure. Mostly because, it is advertised as a feature for just born Lucene/Solr 4.1 [AnalyzingSuggester](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/09/lucenes-new-analyzing-suggester.html). In fact, the article specifically covers your use case:

> With an analyzer that folds or normalizes case, accents, etc. (e.g.,
>   using ICUFoldingFilter), the suggestions will match irrespective of
>   case and accents. For example, the query "ame..." would suggest
>   Amélie.

The problem is that you need to put together a complete example yourself at this point. There is very little guidance. But it (AnalyzingSuggester) is probably your best bet.

Comment: I tried it with the AnalyzingSuggester and attached my changes to my first post (I had the same configuration for a query-analyzer as well, but removing this did not change the outcome, so I guess it's not needed). It seems that I get back the normalized field tho (like it is stored in the index). So `tést`, `test`, `Têst` all gives back `test name`, which is very strange since asug is just a copyField of name and not even stored..?

Comment: I randomly got it "working" - It seems that the Suggester always returns the INDEXED field value instead of the ACTUAL field value.
If I feed the document without index-analyzers, then restart with index-analyzers, I get back the correct field. Unfortunately this obviously can't be used as a final solution :/

Comment: Are you sure you removed the folding analyzer from the _original_ field? As far as I can tell the documentation for AnalyzingSuggester very specifically says that the match is on analyzed (folded) form but the results are on the original surface form. I would check tokens returned from the original field if you are not sure.

And I am not sure where the copyField is coming from, you should not need that for simple scenario.

Comment: The original field is of type "solr.StrField", I created the copyField since I need a "solr.TextField" for the analyzer-part. The original field indeed is unfolded and I can retrieve the correct text from it :/

Comment: My understanding (possibly wrong) is that you don't need to copyField. You point your "field" to the original field, but also provide analyzer-only chain by giving the type in suggestAnalyzerFieldType. It will do the duplication of content all by itself.

Comment: For completeness, [here is a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tN9yXHB0) of Sebastian's working solution, pulled from a discussion he had in the [Suggester page](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/09/lucenes-new-analyzing-suggester.html) Alexandre recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a custom fieldType, perhaps similar to the `text_en` field, but that also implements the [ASCIIFilterFoldingFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) to handle the diacritics conversion at index and query time.

Comment: Thanks Paige, I updated the first post to show the changes done. I'm using KeywordTokenizer to retrieve the whole term (startsWith).
While this retrieves the right document for `asug:"test nâme"` or any other lower/upper/accent-variant, it does not work for the autosuggest implementation. Any idea what would need to be changed? `terms.regex=Test.*` gives me `test name` (should return `Têst Námè`) and specifying any accent in the regex does not give any result at all :(

Comment: I am not sure what would need to be changed to make this work. I have not used the TermsComponent before. In the past for AutoSuggest, I have followed the Suggester - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester outline on the wiki, that essentially uses SpellCheck under the covers.